# How to set expiration date in svn

Tags: svn, svnkit

Hi i am using SVNKit for document Management. I want to set expiration date when user locks the document. But there ia no setter property for expirationDate in SVNLock class. When user locks Document expiration date is set to null by FSRepository.java.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNLock.html#SVNLock(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date)), you need to set the expiration date in the constructor. There aren't setters for any of the other properties of that class, it's all done through the constructor.